# Chkconfig ignores service dependencies

Tags: service, rhel7, systemctl

So I have these 2 files:

```
/etc/init.d
    - service1
    - service2
```

`service2` is like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2346 95 45
# description: desc
# processname: service2

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          service2
# Required-Start:    service1
# Required-Stop:     service1
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 6
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: desc
# Description:       long desc
### END INIT INFO
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jre"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
/opt/do/something.sh $*
```

I want, on normal boot and reboot, `service2` to start after `service1` ends (take about 12 minutes, it's an app-server), but they start almost at the same time and this breaks `service2`.

Why is service system ignoring the dependencies I set up?
Is there something wrong?
Is there a way to check the correctness of boot order execution?

I'm on RHEL7 and both services have been added succesfully with

```
chkconfig --add <service_name>
```

Thank you

Comment: What you're doing wrong is creating old-style init scripts. You should be creating systemd units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Hampton mentioned in the comments, [you should convert your old-style init scripts to systemd units](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/converting-traditional-sysv-init-scripts-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-systemd-unit-files).

However, you may have your reasons to keep using old-style SysVinit scripts.

There may be one problem in your script: I seem to recall that there used to be a requirement that *there must be no blank lines* before the `### BEGIN INIT INFO` line.

I cannot find that requirement in the [current LSB standards document](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html) but I think I once solved a similar problem by removing blank lines from before the INIT INFO section. If my memory is correct, this might explain why your dependencies are not followed.

Also, the dependencies in SysVinit scripts don't necessarily refer to the actual services, but just the scripts themselves: the RHEL7 `systemd` will fire up the `service2` script immediately after `service1` script has finished, regardless of whether the actual service process started by the `service1` has completed its start-up or not. So, if your services take a non-trivial time to start up, the scripts should explicitly wait until the service has completely started up before exiting.

Comment: Blank line removed, same result. But it definitely is the case that service1 script ends waaay before than the process is completed, so service2 will always start too earlier. Thank you!